# Connect 2 different sensor to same ground

Tags: gpio

Can I connect 2 different sensors to same ground pin?
Here's how I pictured it. Sensor1 and Sensor2 are ground of sensor 1 and 2. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must connect them to the Pi ground.  All the Pi ground pins are connected together internally.

Similarly all the 5V pins are connected together to form the 5V power rail and all the 3V3 pins are connected together to form the 3V3 power rail.