# Using two sensors that require the same GPIO pin

Tags: gpio, breadboard

So I'm getting into GPIO and the first thing I want to do is connect a sensor and a RF controller. The thing is both 'sensors' require the same GPIO pins, so my question is can I still use both with a breadboard?

The RF sensor requires GPIO pins 1 to 26 and the sensor requires a 3.3v power pin, a ground pin and a GPIO pin so basically all Id need to do is use a different GPIO pin and ground pin for the sensor but what about the 3.3V power pin since its already being used by the RF controller?[image: Sensor][image: RF board]

Comment: Duplicate of [Connect 2 different sensor to same ground](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32664/connect-2-different-sensor-to-same-ground), and yes, your sensors can share the same ground and 3v3

Comment: @abolotnov so as long as I have enough GPIO pins I could theorically connect as many sensors as I want?

Comment: Well, kinda - whatever you connect drains power, you want to remember that

Comment: What sensors? What pins?

Comment: @Milliways I've uploaded the diagrams

Comment: You have ADDED some images - the first lacking any pin numbers the second presumably the pinout of some unspecified device which we may guess uses some (or all) of the first 26 pins. I see no conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The DHT22 doesn't use a specific protocol, so it can be connected to any GPIO pin not used by another sensor. Assuming your second diagram showing the 26-pin header shows the pins used by your RF sensor as those in lighter green with a label, any of the darker green pins without a label should therefore be fine for the DHT22.

As pointed out in a comment, +3.3V, +5V, and GROUND can be shared between as many devices as needed provided there's enough power for them.